# How to best get a byte array from a ClientResponse from Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, protocol-buffers, reactive-programming, binary-data

I'm trying out the new `WebClient` from Spring 5 (5.0.0.RC2) in a codebase that uses reactive programming and I've had success mapping the JSON response from an endpoint to a DTO in my app, which works very nice:

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create(baseURI);
Mono<DTO> dto = client.get()
        .uri(uri)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(DTO.class));
```

However, now I'm trying to the response body from an endpoint which uses Protocol Buffers (binary data served as `application/octet-stream`), so I'd like to get the raw bytes from the response, which I'll then map to an object myself.

I got it to work like this using `Bytes` from Google Guava:

```
Mono<byte[]> bytes = client.get()
        .uri(uri)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .exchange()
        .flatMapMany(response -> response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()))
        .map(dataBuffer -> {
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = dataBuffer.asByteBuffer();
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
            byteBuffer.get(byteArray, 0, bytes.length);
            return byteArray;
        })
        .reduce(Bytes::concat)
```

This works, but is there an easier, more elegant way to get these bytes?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`ClientResponse.bodyToMono()` in the end uses some `org.springframework.core.codec.Decoder` which claims to support the specified class.

So we should check the class hierarchy of the `Decoder`, in particular where and how the `decodeToMono()` method is implemented.

There is a `StringDecoder` which supports decoding to `String`, a bunch of Jackson-related decoders (used in your DTO example under the hood), and there is also a `ResourceDecoder` which is of particular interest.

`ResourceDecoder` supports `org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource` and `org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource`. `ByteArrayResource` is essentially a wrapper around `byte[]`, so the following code will provide an access to the response body as a byte array:

```
Mono<byte[]> mono = client.get()
            ...
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(response -> response.bodyToMono(ByteArrayResource.class))
            .map(ByteArrayResource::getByteArray);
```

Comment: Note that this will buffer the response and load the entire byte array in to memory.

Comment: I tried the above option for getting pdf file byte array but post writing the byte array into a file, I get "file is corrupted" error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Better options here https://stackoverflow.com/q/46460599/839733

Comment: Given .exchange() is now marked as deprecated what would be the updated code for Spring 6?

Answer (score 1):

Oleg Estekhin's answer gives the OP what he asked for, but it's loading the entire response content in the memory, which is an issue for large responses. To get a chunk of bytes at a time instead, we can do the following:

```
client.get()
  .uri("uri")
  .exchange()
  .flatMapMany { it.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()) }
```

The size of these buffers would be 8192 kb by default; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63109504/839733) answer for changing that if needed.

Note that attempting to do `dataBuffer.asByteBuffer().array()` thrwos an exception if the `ByteBuffer` is not backed by an array.