# How to correctly read Flux<DataBuffer> and convert it to a single inputStream

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I'm using `WebClient` and custom `BodyExtractor`class for my spring-boot application

```
WebClient webLCient = WebClient.create();
webClient.get()
   .uri(url, params)
   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION.XML)
   .exchange()
   .flatMap(response -> {
     return response.body(new BodyExtractor());
   })
```

BodyExtractor.java

```
@Override
public Mono<T> extract(ClientHttpResponse response, BodyExtractor.Context context) {
  Flux<DataBuffer> body = response.getBody();
  body.map(dataBuffer -> {
    try {
      JaxBContext jc = JaxBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class);
      Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

      return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(dataBuffer.asInputStream())
    } catch(Exception e){
       return null;
    }
  }).next();
}
```

Above code works with small payload but not on a large payload, I think it's because I'm only reading a single flux value with `next` and I'm not sure how to combine and read all `dataBuffer`.

I'm new to reactor, so I don't know a lot of tricks with flux/mono.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to make it work by using `Flux#collect` and `SequenceInputStream`

```
@Override
public Mono<T> extract(ClientHttpResponse response, BodyExtractor.Context context) {
  Flux<DataBuffer> body = response.getBody();
  return body.collect(InputStreamCollector::new, (t, dataBuffer)-> t.collectInputStream(dataBuffer.asInputStream))
    .map(inputStream -> {
      try {
        JaxBContext jc = JaxBContext.newInstance(SomeClass.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

        return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
      } catch(Exception e){
        return null;
      }
  }).next();
}
```

`InputStreamCollector.java`

```
public class InputStreamCollector {
  private InputStream is;

  public void collectInputStream(InputStream is) {
    if (this.is == null) this.is = is;
    this.is = new SequenceInputStream(this.is, is);
  }

  public InputStream getInputStream() {
    return this.is;
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you writing your own BodyExtractor? WebFlux already supports Jaxb with Jaxb2XmlDecoder.

Comment: @BrianClozel do I need to configure something for it to work? `bodyToMono` doesn't seem to pick up my pojo's.

Comment: What's `InputStreamCollector`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar please check my usage above.

Comment: Interesting, but `WebClient` is the wrong tool for this job. You're reconstructing the response `InputStream`, so you get no advantage of using `WebClient`. You're better off using a plain vanilla HTTP client.

Comment: Isn't this solution reads all response body into memory? `ByteBuffer` stores all it's data in memory, right? So resulting `InputStream` will be the same as `ByteArrayInputStream`, so this solution doesn't handle big data.

Comment: I am using a similar approach.  Two recommendations I would add 1. to hold a reference to the `JAXBContext` and 2. reuse use `dataBuffer.asInputStream(true)`, so than an eventual close of the inputStream will close also the dataBuffer

Comment: thank you very much, i had to reprocess some files while uploading, i had to collect all chunks. You can run in all kinds of problems with large files.

Answer (score 28):

This is really not as complicated as other answers imply.

The only way to stream the data without buffering it all in memory is to use a pipe, as @jin-kwon suggested. However, it can be done very simply by using Spring's [BodyExtractors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyExtractors.html) and [DataBufferUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html) utility classes.

Example:

```java
private InputStream readAsInputStream(String url) throws IOException {
    PipedOutputStream osPipe = new PipedOutputStream();
    PipedInputStream isPipe = new PipedInputStream(osPipe);

    ClientResponse response = webClient.get().uri(url)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION.XML)
        .exchange()
        .block();
    final int statusCode = response.rawStatusCode();
    // check HTTP status code, can throw exception if needed
    // ....

    Flux<DataBuffer> body = response.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers())
        .doOnError(t -> {
            log.error("Error reading body.", t);
            // close pipe to force InputStream to error,
            // otherwise the returned InputStream will hang forever if an error occurs
            try(isPipe) {
              //no-op
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                log.error("Error closing streams", ioe);
            }
        })
        .doFinally(s -> {
            try(osPipe) {
              //no-op
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                log.error("Error closing streams", ioe);
            }
        });

    DataBufferUtils.write(body, osPipe)
        .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());

    return isPipe;
}
```

If you don't care about checking the response code or throwing an exception for a failure status code, you can skip the `block()` call and intermediate `ClientResponse` variable by using

```java
flatMap(r -> r.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()))
```

instead.

Comment: looks promising and simple, this is probably the proper answer to handle large requests. I'll try this one out if I have the time.

Comment: I should add that I do agree with @abhijit-sarkar's earlier [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460599/how-to-correctly-read-fluxdatabuffer-and-convert-it-to-a-single-inputstream/58272048?noredirect=1#comment82572640_46462424) that `WebClient` is not the best tool for this job. Although it can be done (as I have demonstrated), it is not the most efficient way of doing this. If all you need is an `InputStream`, you are better off using a synchronous client such as `java.net.http.HttpClient`. If you are stuck with `WebClient`, then I believe my solution is the best option.

Comment: It seems like if there's no error, `isPipe` never gets closed

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, There is no need to close `isPipe` here. That would be the responsibility of the caller of this `readAsInputStream()` method (i.e. to use the `InputStream` in a try-with-resources block).  The `doFinally()` here ensures that `osPipe` always gets closed, and that will trigger a call to the sink (`isPipe`) that the end of the input has been reached and it will return -1/EOF on the next read.

Comment: Change `PipedInputSteam` to `PipedInputStream` and `MediaType.APPLICATION.XML` to `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`. I get rid of the status code so i need to use `flatMapMany(r -> r.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()))` instead of `flatMap(r -> r.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers()))`

Comment: Try with resources for variable declared outside of try block, requires minimum java version of 9

Comment: Did not work using Java 8 using reactor-core 3.3.9.RELEASE. The PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream contain only 0's with no termination. It hangs my unmarshaller in the call unmarshaller.unmarshal(isPipe). In fact, in my debugger, the doFinally never gets called, which is suspect

Comment: did not work getting ``java.io.IOException pipe not connected`` , any clue on this

Comment: .exchange() is deprecated.  Any alternative way? @user1585916

Comment: using `.exchangeToFlux(x -> { return x.body(BodyExtractors.toDataBuffers() .... })` works as also substituting `try-with-resources` with simple `try { isPipe.close(); } catch...` does too (on `Spring Boot 2.7.6` / `Java 8`)

Answer (score 10):

A slightly modified version of Bk Santiago's answer makes use of `reduce()` instead of `collect()`. Very similar, but doesn't require an extra class:

Java:

```
body.reduce(new InputStream() {
    public int read() { return -1; }
  }, (s: InputStream, d: DataBuffer) -> new SequenceInputStream(s, d.asInputStream())
).flatMap(inputStream -> /* do something with single InputStream */
```

Or Kotlin:

```
body.reduce(object : InputStream() {
  override fun read() = -1
}) { s: InputStream, d -> SequenceInputStream(s, d.asInputStream()) }
  .flatMap { inputStream -> /* do something with single InputStream */ }
```

Benefit of this approach over using `collect()` is simply you don't need to have a different class to gather things up.

I created a new empty `InputStream()`, but if that syntax is confusing, you can also replace it with `ByteArrayInputStream("".toByteArray())` instead to create an empty `ByteArrayInputStream` as your initial value instead.

Comment: Instead of `new InputStream() {
    public int read() { return -1; }
  }` you can use `InputStream.nullInputStream()`

Answer (score 7):

Here comes another variant from other answers. And it's still not memory-friendly.

```
static Mono<InputStream> asStream(WebClient.ResponseSpec response) {
    return response.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class)
        .map(b -> b.asInputStream(true))
        .reduce(SequenceInputStream::new);
}

static void doSome(WebClient.ResponseSpec response) {
    asStream(response)
        .doOnNext(stream -> {
            // do some with stream
            // close the stream!!!
        })
        .block();
}
```

Comment: Super easy when dealing with small files.

Comment: @Tires I really doubt about `DataBuffer::asInputStream`. See [asInputStream()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBuffer.html#asInputStream--)

Comment: @JinKwon You're right. I'm wondering why I don't see the Netty warning about unreleased buffers before

Comment: Be careful. If you close the SequenceInputStream (you should otherwise you will get unreleased buffer errors from Netty) then it can cause a StackoverflowError very easily if you have a big file or lots of small buffers.

Answer (score 4):

There's a much cleaner way to do this using the underlying reactor-netty `HttpClient` directly, instead of using `WebClient`. The composition hierarchy is like this:

```
WebClient -uses-> HttpClient -uses-> TcpClient
```

Easier to show code than explain:

```
HttpClient.create()
    .get()
    .responseContent() // ByteBufFlux
    .aggregate() // ByteBufMono
    .asInputStream() // Mono<InputStream>
    .block() // We got an InputStream, yay!
```

However, as I've pointed out already, using `InputStream` is a blocking operation, that defeats the purpose of using a non-blocking HTTP client, not to mention aggregating the whole response. See [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html) for a Java NIO vs. IO comparison.

Comment: I understand that using the InputStream is blocking operation. However imagine scenario where I need to get some xml file from other server and then use some data from the xml. At that point I would like to get the file non blocking way and then I just need to parse it. Isn't this a way to go? I don't wanna block the thread when doing the network call but when I have whole response with all the data I am ok with conversion to InputStream or parsing it blocking way. Or is there a catch I am missing (e.g. the whole operation including network call have to be blocking with this apporach)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use pipes.

```
static <R> Mono<R> pipeAndApply(
        final Publisher<DataBuffer> source, final Executor executor,
        final Function<? super ReadableByteChannel, ? extends R> function) {
    return using(Pipe::open,
                 p -> {
                     executor.execute(() -> write(source, p.sink())
                             .doFinally(s -> {
                                 try {
                                     p.sink().close();
                                 } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                                     log.error("failed to close pipe.sink", ioe);
                                     throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                                 }
                             })
                             .subscribe(releaseConsumer()));
                     return just(function.apply(p.source()));
                 },
                 p -> {
                     try {
                         p.source().close();
                     } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                         log.error("failed to close pipe.source", ioe);
                         throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                     }
                 });
}
```

Or using `CompletableFuture`,

```
static <R> Mono<R> pipeAndApply(
        final Publisher<DataBuffer> source,
        final Function<? super ReadableByteChannel, ? extends R> function) {
    return using(Pipe::open,
                 p -> fromFuture(supplyAsync(() -> function.apply(p.source())))
                         .doFirst(() -> write(source, p.sink())
                                 .doFinally(s -> {
                                     try {
                                         p.sink().close();
                                     } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                                         log.error("failed to close pipe.sink", ioe);
                                         throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                                     }
                                 })
                                 .subscribe(releaseConsumer())),
                 p -> {
                     try {
                         p.source().close();
                     } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                         log.error("failed to close pipe.source", ioe);
                         throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
                     }
                 });
}
```